# incorrectly printing string in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node {
    char courseID[6];
    int section;
    int credits;
    struct node *link;
};

int main(void)
{
    int run=1;
    char coursetemp[6];
    int option, num, num2;
    struct node *ptr;
    void add(struct node **, int, int, char[]);
    void display(struct node *);
    void del(struct node *, int);

    ptr = NULL;
    while (run==1)
    {
        printf("Main Menu\n 1. Add Course\n2.Delete Course\n3. Display Enrolled courses\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        if (option == 1)
        {
            printf("Please enter the course ID\n");
            scanf("%s", coursetemp);
            printf("Please enter the course section, and amount of credits it's worth\n");
            scanf("%d %d", &num, &num2);
            add(&ptr, num, num2, coursetemp);
            display(ptr);
        }
        if (option == 2)
        {
            printf("Enter the element to delete\n");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            del(ptr, num);
        }
        if (option == 3)
        {
            display(ptr);
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("Please enter a proper selection\n");
        }   //end of while
    }
    return 0;
}  
void display(struct node *pt)
{
    while (pt != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d\n", pt->courseID, pt->section, pt->credits);
        pt = pt->link;
    }
}
```

This works as I intend it to, as long as the course name is only letters. But as soon as I try it with letters and nums ex. CIS444 I get a bunch of random ascii characters. I feel like it is a simple fix yet I don't recall how to

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please add input which breaks your program.

Comment: If there is any numbers in the string, it prints out wrong characters. (ex CIS120)

Comment: `CIS120` is 6 characters long and by that to large for a `char[6]`, since you need to save the termination symbol. You need at least `char[7]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are typing in a course ID of 6 or more characters.  The `courseID` member can only hold a 5 character ID with a null terminator on the end.  If, for example, you entered a 6 character course ID, then it would copy 7 bytes into `courseID` and, depending on structure alignment, overwrite part of the following member in the structure.  Note, too, that in this case, the variable `coursetemp` would also be written past the end (resulting in undefined behavior).

Comment: +1: This seems to be the problem, since OP stated `CIS120` as example input.